# PySpark sum of last values by ID over timeseries window

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have this DataFrame in PySpark:

```
[Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 6095), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 15215), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 25456), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 35641), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 44516), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 106098), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 108248), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 118453), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 129638), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 138515), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 206095), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 215213), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 225445), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 234635), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 244514), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 306095), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 309226), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 319454), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 329651), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 337523), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 406077), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 415209), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 425481), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 435638), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 445548), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 506073), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 508245), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 519452), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 529641), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 537512), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 606087), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 615193), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 625452), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 635632), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 645538), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 706073), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 709212), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 718452), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 729642), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 738524), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 806095), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 815210), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 825455), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 834640), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 844520), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 906083), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 908243), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 918445), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 929632), timestamp=1532354662),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 938511), timestamp=1532354662)]
```

**I need to sum only last known *value* for each *id* in second window.**

Outpt should look like this:

```
 [Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22), sum=176213),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 23), sum=176112),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 24), sum=175933),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 25), sum=175543),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 26), sum=175219),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 27), sum=175002),
 Row(time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 28), sum=174892)...]
```

I have tried this:

```
w = Window.partitionBy(F.col('id')).orderBy('timestamp')
_df.withColumn('last_known', F.last('value').over(w)).sort('time').take(1000)
```

and it produces new column with last known value for each id, but I don`t know how to sum it.

```
[Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 6095), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 15215), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 25456), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 35641), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 44516), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 106098), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 108248), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 118453), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 129638), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 138515), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 206095), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 215213), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 225445), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 234635), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 244514), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35185, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 306095), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 309226), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 319454), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 329651), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 337523), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 406077), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 415209), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 425481), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 435638), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 445548), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 506073), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 508245), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 519452), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 529641), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 537512), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 606087), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 615193), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 625452), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35276, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 635632), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 645538), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 706073), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 709212), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 718452), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 729642), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 738524), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 806095), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 815210), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 825455), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 834640), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 844520), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187),
 Row(id='487', value=35184, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 906083), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35184),
 Row(id='489', value=35285, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 908243), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35285),
 Row(id='48B', value=35211, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 918445), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35211),
 Row(id='48D', value=35275, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 929632), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35275),
 Row(id='48F', value=35187, time=datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 23, 14, 4, 22, 938511), timestamp=1532354662, last_known=35187)]
```

Other solution is:

```
_df.orderBy('time').groupBy('timestamp', 'id').agg(F.last('value').alias('last'))\
.groupBy('timestamp').agg(F.sum('last').alias('sum'))\
.sort('timestamp').take(50)
```

Output looks promising, but double aggregate seems like asking for troubles... and it should run on TB of data, so speed is concern too.

```
[Row(timestamp=1532354662, sum=176142),
 Row(timestamp=1532354663, sum=176142),
 Row(timestamp=1532354664, sum=176139),
 Row(timestamp=1532354665, sum=176137),
 Row(timestamp=1532354666, sum=176133),
 Row(timestamp=1532354667, sum=176128),
 Row(timestamp=1532354668, sum=176125),
 Row(timestamp=1532354669, sum=176122),
 Row(timestamp=1532354670, sum=176120),
 Row(timestamp=1532354671, sum=176118),
 Row(timestamp=1532354672, sum=176117),
 Row(timestamp=1532354673, sum=176114),
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT
Terry`s answer is best right now. If someone has better idea please post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can replace your first groupBy for a 'dropDuplicates' and set ascending = False in orderBy. Like this:

```
df.orderBy(['time'], ascending = False) \
.dropDuplicates(['timestamp', 'id']) \
.groupBy('timestamp').agg(F.sum('value').alias('sum')).sort('timestamp').show()
```